# Create a legend on basis of the x-axis values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following example code:

```
tmp <- data.frame("channel_topic" = LETTERS[seq(from = 1, to = 16)],
                  "n_group" = round(seq(from = 1600, to = 0, length.out = 16)),
                  "group_id_for_plot" = 1:16)

ggplot(tmp) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(
      x = group_id_for_plot,
      y = n_group#, fill = channel_topic
    ),
    stat = "identity"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = group_id_for_plot,
      y = n_group,
      label = n_group
    ),
    vjust = -1
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "Anzahl",
    subtitle = paste("N = ", nrow(data_single_group), sep = ""),
    fill = "channel topic"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:16) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                    colour = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey95"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title.align = 0.5
  ) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1650))
```

Is there a possibility to get the variable *channel_topics* in a legend under the plot without using the *fill asthetic*? In my real code the *channel_topics* are very long and all the solutions with rotating or dodging the labels don't suit my style.

Maybe with a factor? Unfortunately I can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what it is you want the legend to show? If the channel_topic names don't fit in the legend, then what does the fact that they are mapped to the fill scale matter? If they don't fit, they don't fit, and something has to give. Maybe include a sketch of the expected output?

Comment: The channel_topics don't fit as x-axis, so I want the group_id_plot on the x_axis and the channel_topics in the legend.

Comment: But if you remove the commented out line, that's excatly what you have at the moment. What is it that you want to be different? Do you just not want the different colors to be present in the plot / legend?

Comment: Exactly. I don't want the colors and instead something like 1: A, 2: B, 3: C ...

Comment: OK. You can do that. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fill` aesthetic, but hide the key glyphs in the legend, and draw a second `geom_col` layer over the top of the coloured one:

```r
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = group_id_for_plot, y = n_group)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = factor(paste(group_id_for_plot, '=', channel_topic),
                             paste(group_id_for_plot, '=', channel_topic))), 
               key_glyph = draw_key_blank) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n_group), vjust = -1) +
  scale_y_continuous('Anzahl', limits = c(0, 1650)) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = 1:16) +
  labs(subtitle = paste0("N = ", nrow(tmp)), fill = "channel topic") +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                    colour = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey95"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    legend.key.size = unit(0, 'mm')
  )
```

[image]